# Up-to-Date check claims build input "is missing" when the file exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

After copying the entire solution directory from one folder to another and making ZERO changes I run into an annoying bug in the build process.

Every time I build, even when no file is changed, every cpp file is recompiled. This continues to happen after building a couple times without making any changes in the new solution folder.

Increasing the **Tools** > **Options** > **Projects and Solutions** > **Build and Run** > **MSBuild project build output verbosity** to `Detailed` shows the error:

> ------ Up-To-Date check: Project: project, Configuration: Release x64 ------
>
> Project is not up-to-date: build input 'd:\projects\project\project\stdafx.cpp' is missing.

Now, `stdafx.cpp` is not missing and `stdafx.obj` is in the release folder.  It also has nothing to do with this file in particular.  If I were to delete `stdafx.cpp` which is not really needed the missing file complaint just moves to the next file in the compile list (in my case, that's `glad.c`.)

The original solution folder does not have this error. Is there anything else you need? I am a long time linux developer (emacs/make/cmake/g++/gdb/git etc are my environment of choice) recently using visual studio.

Comment: When you make a copy, do you preserve file timestamps? If timestamps are modified, VS has no other choice than to recompile.

Comment: I don't mind if the timestamps get borked the first time and forces a recompile. The issue is that after compiling once the issue persists in perpetuity.

Comment: They're not saying the obj is out of date. They're saying the file itself is missing, and determine (i.e. guess) building the project must somehow generate it (which of course, isn't true). The most common (and irritating) time I see this is when some source file (or header; whatever) is removed from disk, but not from the project itself. It will exhibit the same symptoms. Normally file paths are relative to the project file. If yours are not you may have to text-edit the .vcprojx file and manually change the path names within.

Comment: Also check includes for each file.  Some might be missing stdafx.h

Comment: All of the cpp files are present in the project folder base, nothing exotic. Again, this issue does not even appear in the original directory. Only the copied directory.

Comment: Could it be that the directory target for the update check is pointing to the wrong place but obviously the project is pointing to the right place since it compiles and runs fine. Where can I check to see where the update check is pointing?

Comment: Would you please share the project file `.vcxproj` to us? Have you check if the path of those files in the project file are relative path? If not, you should use relative path to include those file. And have you tried create a new project to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> I am a long time linux developer (emacs/make/cmake/g++/gdb/git etc are my environment of choice) recently using visual studio.

Then if you're like me, you might be dealing with some kind of hybridization of filesystems in which a case-sensitivity/case-insensitivity issue is biting you.

I ran into the problem because I enabled the [case sensitivity support](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-ntfs-treat-folders-case-sensitive-windows-10) which is available when you install the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).  But I'm sure others using various virtualization schemes and mounting foreign filesystems can wind up with a "case-preserving, but not case-insensitive" scenario.

What I gather is that MSBuild turns file paths to all lowercase as part of a canonization process (including resolving relative paths) in order to do its figuring.  So even if you have the casing all correct in your .vcxproj, it will throw it out before sniffing the path for availability.  It may break the path down and do requests one directory at a time, or otherwise be doing something that leads it to report lack of existence of a file which simply requesting the full path via "dir" in a shell wouldn't expose.

In any case, disabling the case-sensitivity switch on a folder in the path (that particular folder's name had an uppercase character) made the issue go away.

> After copying the entire solution directory from one folder to another and making ZERO changes I run into an annoying bug in the build process.

...and this suggests it's very likely the case-sensitivity problem.